# symfony2 set request parameter to custom annotation

Tags: symfony, annotations

I want use request parameter in my annotation in Symfony2
I want set $id (it is parameter from request) to MyAnnotation, as it described below

```
/**
 * @MyAnnotation($id)
 * @Route('something/{id}')
 *
 */
```

When I set $id in this way, I have an error. How to pass this parameter to annotation?
Other way is:

```
/**
 * @MyAnnotation("id")
 * @Route('something/{id}')
 *
 */
```

And I can get value of "id" parameter in annotation class, in constructor:

```
public function __construct($options)
{
    // get key
    $key = $options['value'];
    // get value of key
    $id = $request->get($key);
}
```

But I dont know its possible to set $id in annotation and dont write code in constructor.

Comment: The question needs to be clarified. What outcome do you expect here? Looks like you want to pass an action parameter into an annotation, however this is not what annotations are for, basically. Perhaps an event listener would help you here?
Please provide some more context.

Comment: I described question